# How to use InternalId to get text in the QTreeView on PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am a Python Fan and a Novice. I found when I use InternalPointer get text(item) in QTreeView can occur crashes, so I search workaround on google, I found InternalId, but it return int, but I want to use it to get text, eh I don't know how to use it.
I toss a long time, but really don't understand, so I want to ask you to help me solve this problem.
hoping to Simple and Easy to understand:)
Thank you very much!

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.Qt import *

class TreeView(QtGui.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TreeView, self).__init__(parent)          
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL("clicked(QModelIndex)"), self.getCurrentIndex)

    def getCurrentIndex(self, index):
        # Use 'InternalId' obtain the corresponding text, not int and hoping to simple.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    model = QtGui.QDirModel()
    tree = TreeView()
    tree.setModel(model)
    tree.setWindowTitle(tree.tr("Dir View"))
    tree.resize(640, 480)
    tree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [data method](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmodelindex.html#data) to get the text

Also you may prefer to use the new style of connecting signals slot [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html)

```
class TreeView(QtGui.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TreeView, self).__init__(parent)      
        self.clicked.connect(self.getCurrentIndex)    
        # self.connect(self, SIGNAL("clicked(QModelIndex)"), self.getCurrentIndex)

    def getCurrentIndex(self, index):
        print(index.data())
        # Use 'InternalId' obtain the corresponding text, not int and hoping to simple.
```